# Julia & NetCDF: Build/install fails

Tags: julia, netcdf

The first instruction for installing the NetCDF module is failing with the following behavior:

```
julia> Pkg.build("NetCDF")
INFO: Building NetCDF
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: ................
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Users\James\.julia\v0.4\Conda\deps\usr:
#
libnetcdf                 4.3.3.1                       3
===============================[ ERROR: NetCDF ]================================


LoadError: Provider BinDeps.PackageManager failed to satisfy dependency libnetcdf
while loading C:\Users\James\.julia\v0.4\NetCDF\deps\build.jl, in expression starting on line 12

================================================================================


================================[ BUILD ERRORS ]================================


WARNING: NetCDF had build errors.
```

I am using a Windows machine with NetCDF version 4.3.3.1 installed. What can I try to get around this? Perhaps I need to find the directory containing libnetcdf and specify this directory as the value of an environment variable?

Comment: it seems this package is not ready for julia-0.4. http://pkg.julialang.org/detail/NetCDF.html

Comment: I get the same error on Windows machine